# is this usage of like correct?

Tags: as-like

This computer program treats photonic crystals **like** a periodic set of cylinders

I am having a hard time to figure out if I should use like or as in this sentence.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "as" when you say "us", either is possible, with a  slight difference in meaning.

If you use "as", you have the particular verb "treat X as Y", which means that the thing is really an X, but you will behave as though it was really a Y.

If you use "like", that is less specific: something about the way you are treating X likens them to Y, but it is not necessarily pretending that they are Y.

Comment: Another useful way of encapsulating that (sometimes fine) nuance of difference is to say ***as = as if it were*** (*actually* Y instead of X), whereas ***like*** can simply mean ***similar*** (not ***identical***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do the rules of the site permit me to comment, "Thanks. I can go to bed now. I've learnt my something new and useful for today"? :)

Comment: @Ross: Only if you're over 50! (If you're younger, you should have lain in bed tossing and turning, thinking *Why did he write **were** instead of **was**?* :)